# Female Starship Pilot Novel

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a recent novel about a female starship pilot/captain who crash lands with her ship's passengers and a security robot and has to survive against hostile creatures with the increasingly dwindling ammunition of her robot.

Its a very recent novel. I only saw it the month before last. I came across it on Amazon. Its an ebook, as far as I can remember. I'm afraid I don't remember the cover art, but there was a tiny ship zipping at the top corner of the cover, and a woman's face somewhere in the centre.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you come across it?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: I came across it on Amazon. Its an E Book, as far as I can remember. I'm afraid I don't remember the cover art, but there was a tiny ship zipping at the top corner of the cover, and a woman's face somewhere in the centre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's *very* recent it could be [Captain Freya - An Alien Adventure](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/63038438-captain-freya---an-alien-adventure) by Steve Dean.

[image: Captain Freya - An Alien Adventure]

> Flight Officer Freya Webb is flying a shuttle full of scientists and their equipment to a remote research base on a recently discovered exoplanet. The craft suddenly loses all power and crashlands in a desert of purple sand. The situation worsens when a quake causes the shuttle to sink into the vibrating sand, taking all their supplies with it, save only for a robotic bodyguard.
>
> With little hope of rescue, Freya decides to lead the group back to base herself, although she’s not exactly sure where it is.
>
> Only Freya’s wits and the robot’s rapidly shrinking supply of ammunition keep them alive as they’re stalked by a growing number of increasingly large predators. She vows to save as many of the scientists as possible, but as the days pass and the danger grows, she starts to think this might not be any at all. Herself included.
>
> When the group is helped by a very unlikely ally, discovered by one of the scientists, Freya begins to wonder if they have anything else useful to contribute to the situation and if they can be persuaded to work together to provide the edge they so desperately need.

Goodreads gives the publication date as December 1st 2022, and it was published as an ebook. If you saw it on Amazon [it would be this post](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BJLGT813).

Comment: Yes! This is indeed the story I was looking for. Thank you so much...